# How to return the sum of all the numbers in a string?

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, sum

I want to sum all the numbers in the string 'your 3 cents is not equal to my 600
dollars'. The expected output is 603.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT sum(s) 
FROM (select regexp_split_to_table('your 3 cents is not equal to my 600 
dollars','\d{1,}')) as s;
```

But I am getting the error "function sum(record) does not exist".

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `regexp_matches()` to extract the strings to a set of arrays, then casting and aggregation:

```
select sum(val[1]::int) res
from regexp_matches('your 3 cents is not equal to my 600 dollars','\d+', 'g') x(val)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2c856b40d4137e8c688d7268683ece2c)**:

```
| res |
| --: |
| 603 |
```